# Extract href given text of anchor tag using Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract url from the href attribute given specific text of the anchor tag.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from nba.items import NBAItem

class ESPNSpider(Spider):
    name = "ESPN"
    allowed_domains = ["espn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://espn.go.com/nba/teams"]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[1]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = NBAItem()
        item['team_name'] = site.xpath('//a[@class="bi"]/text()').extract()
        item['team_link'] = site.xpath('//a[@class="bi"]/@href').extract()
        item['team_stats_link'] = site.xpath('//a[text()='Stats']/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

This is the line I am having trouble with:

```
item['team_stats_link'] = site.xpath('//a[text()='Stats']/@href').extract()
```

I have also attempted:

```
item['team_stats_link'] = site.xpath('//a[contains(text(), 'Stats')]/@href).extract()
```

The website in question: http://espn.go.com/nba/teams

Comment: `site.xpath('//a[text()='Stats']/@href')` is a Python syntax error. Take a look at the single quotes.

Comment: Ah! All this time. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath inside the loop should start with `.//`, in other words, you need to make it relative to the `site`.

I'd also go through `li` tags inside the `ul` with `medium-logos` class instead of searching for the first `div` inside the third `div` inside the `div` with `content` id:

```
class ESPNSpider(Spider):
    name = "ESPN"
    allowed_domains = ["espn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://espn.go.com/nba/teams"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="medium-logos"]//li')
        for site in sites:
            item = NBAItem()
            item['team_name'] = site.xpath('.//a[@class="bi"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['team_link'] = site.xpath('.//a[@class="bi"]/@href').extract()[0]
            item['team_stats_link'] = site.xpath(".//a[text()='Stats']/@href").extract()[0]
            yield item
```

It produces:

```
{'team_link': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bos/boston-celtics', 'team_name': u'Boston Celtics', 'team_stats_link': u'/nba/teams/stats?team=bos'}
{'team_link': u'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bkn/brooklyn-nets', 'team_name': u'Brooklyn Nets', 'team_stats_link': u'/nba/teams/stats?team=bkn'}
...
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it is you would go with the relative path? Also, why go through the `medium-logos` class rather than the `bi` class?

Comment: @user1636797 I do still use `bi` to find `name` and `link` of a team. You need to make it relative so that you'll search inside the team block instead of a whole page. Hope that helps.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: What is the `.extract()[0]` doing that is different from `.extract()`?

Comment: @user1636797 sorry, forgot mentioning. `extract()` returns a list of results, while you need just the first result out of it.